# Jess doesn't have or doesn't find FuzzyVariable package on Linux and macOS

Tags: linux, macos, jess

I am doing my homework or my school workclass/assignment presentation about questions of Unknown Region planets, using parsecs, diameter and temperature units, on Mac and Linux. I applied FuzzyVariable to the planets names and units.

I added `(import nrc.fuzzy.*)`.

```
;Distância do Coruscant
(defglobal ?*gVarDistanciaDeCoruscant* = (new nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyVariable "distanciaDeCoruscant" 0.0 30000.0 "parsecs"))

;Temperatura dos Planetas
(defglobal ?*gVarTemperatura* = (new nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyVariable "temperatura" 0 8000 "K"))

;Planetas Vizinhos
(defglobal ?*gVarPlanetasVizinhos* = (new nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyVariable "distanciaPlanetasVizinhos" 0.0 400000.0 "d"))

;Raio em termos de unidades coruscantenses
(defglobal ?*gVarTamanho* = (new nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyVariable "tamanho" 0 500 "EU"))

;Quando o planeta foi descoberto
(defglobal ?*gVarDescobertaTempo* = (new nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyVariable "descoberta" 50000BBY 400ABY))

(call nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyValue setMatchThreshold 0.1)
```

And the terminal, Jess gave the error:

```
Jess reported an error in routine new
    while executing (new nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyVariable "distanciaDeCoruscant" 0.0 30000.0 "parsec")
    while executing definition for defglobal ?*gVarDistanciaDeCoruscant*
    while executing (batch "/Users/UNISAL/Documents/AI/StarWars.clp").
  Message: Class nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyVariable not found.
  Program text: ( defglobal ?*gVarDistanciaDeCoruscant* = ( new nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyVariable "distanciaDeCoruscant" 0.0 30000.0 "parsec" ) )  at line 26 in file /Users/UNISAL/Documents/AI/StarWars.clp.

Nested exception is:
nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyVariable
```

I think Mac and Linux do not have this package for Jess. Is it possible to add a missed package compatible with Mac and Linux?

I need to deliver my workclass/assignment presentation to my teacher for getting good grade.

You can check the whole document: https://gist.github.com/gusbemacbe/8ad836256edcfb5edbffe206cad6c9e8

Comment: Very likely CLASSPATH isn't set to include `nrc.fuzzy.FuzzyVariable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base Jess distribution doesn't include FuzzyJ; you have to install it separately, include it in the classpath, and then launch with FuzzyMain instead of the standard Jess.Main. Your instructor should have told you all this. If you don't have FuzzyJ you can download it from the "User Contributions" page at the Jess web site: http://www.jessrules.com/contributions/ .

Comment: I read the installation instructions, but I am confused. Does it ask me to extract fuzzyJ12.jar and copy one of classes? or just add a class path of fuzzyJ12.jar to the clp file?

Comment: The "classpath" refers to information you give to Java when starting a program; by the time a Jess script is being read, it's too late.  You don't extract the jar files.

Comment: My teacher's fail. I read that to add Fuzzy's jar to Jess, I have to use Eclipse and JessIDE plugins, but when I copied JessIDE feature and plugins to feature and plugins folders of Eclipse, JessIDE didn't appear. I put in the `myusername/.p2/pool/plugins` and also `Eclipse.app/...Eclipse/plugins`.